# R: updating data table columns by reference using a function with 'if'

Tags: r, reference, data.table, lapply

I want to set values in several columns in a data table to 1 if they are greater than 1.

I have tried many different things. The code seems like it ought to work but gives me the message below the code and deletes the first column (V1)

```
DT <-as.data.table(matrix(1:9, 3,3))
  cList <- c("V1","V2")
  DT[,(cList) := lapply(.SD, function(x)  if (x > 1) 1),.SDcols = cList]

Warning messages:
1: In if (x > 1) 1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x > 1) 1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any suggestions greatly (!) appreciated.

Comment: `x` is a vector and `if` accepts expressions of length one. You could solve this using `ifelse`, but if I were you, I would go with `for (j in cList) set(DT, i = which(DT[[j]] > 1L), j = j, value = 1L)` or the `ifelse` way (not recommended) would be `DT[, (cList) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x > 1L, 1L, x)), .SDcols = cList]`

Comment: Maybe `DT[, (cList) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x > 1, 1) ), .SDcols=cList ]` might be a bit faster to do it all within the `DT[]` type code. @DavidArenburg 's first bit of data.table code is probably ideal for speed however.

Comment: I went with what you suggested, involving set(DT...). Worked like a charm. I had tried to use set before but didn't think to use which with it. How do I give this answer the check mark?

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments by David, you are getting warning because if will take only the first element while evaluating the condition. Hence you can use ifelse, which is vectorised.

Here is my alternative solution using pmin.

```
DT <-as.data.table(matrix(1:9, 3,3))
cList <- c("V1","V2")

DT[, (cList) := lapply(.SD, function(x) pmin(1, x) ), .SDcols=cList]
```

Hope this helps.